# Using Conditionalpanel Function in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create the scenario whereby using conditionalpanel, I am able to have an user input of checked boxes to display either 1 or 2 plots, one after another.

My reproducible code can be found below, however, I am unable to display the plots.

Could someone please share with me where did I make a mistake?

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Plot1 or Plot2?"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("my_choices", "Plot1 or Plot2",choices = c("Plot1", "Plot2"), selected = "Plot1"),width=2),
    mainPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.my_choices == 'Plot1'",
        plotOutput("plot1")
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.my_choices == 'Plot2'",
        plotOutput("plot2")
      ), 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.my_choices.includes('Plot1', 'Plot2')",
        plotOutput("plot1"),
        plotOutput("plot2")
      )
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({plot(iris)})
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({plot(mtcars)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Update:

I've got what I wanted but without using ConditionalPanel function. Here's the code below:

Would appreciate if someone can share with me the proper way of using ConditionalPanel Function! (:

```
library(shiny)

#data
df <- iris

#ui
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "Question",
                         label = "Choose the plots",
                         choices = c("Plot1", "Plot2", "Plot3"),
                         selected = "")),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput('ui_plot') 
    )
  )

#server
server <- function(input, output)
{
  # gen plot containers
  output$ui_plot <- renderUI({ 
    out <- list()
    if (length(input$Question)==0){return(NULL)}
    for (i in 1:length(input$Question)){
      out[[i]] <-  plotOutput(outputId = paste0("plot",i))
    }  
    return(out) 
  })

  # render plots
  observe({  
    for (i in 1:3){  
      local({  #because expressions are evaluated at app init
        ii <- i 
        output[[paste0('plot',ii)]] <- renderPlot({ 
          if ( length(input$Question) > ii-1 ){  
            return(plot(runif(100)))
          } 
          NULL
        })
      })
    }                                  

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would give you an alternative as you will need to create new plots with different `id` in order for that to work. The simplest one I can think of is using `shinyjs` package and its `hide` and `show` functions. You can also do this via `renderUI` but you shouldn't give unnecessary work to your server only if you're showing and hiding the elements

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui = fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Plot1 or Plot2?"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("my_choices", "Plot1 or Plot2",choices = c("Plot1", "Plot2"), selected = "Plot1"),width=2),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1"),
      plotOutput("plot2")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output,session) {

  # hide plots on start
  hide("plot1");hide("plot2")

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({plot(iris)})
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({plot(mtcars)})

  observeEvent(input$my_choices,{

    if(is.null(input$my_choices)){
      hide("plot1"); hide("plot2")
    }

    else if(length(input$my_choices) == 1){
      if(input$my_choices == "Plot1"){
        show("plot1");hide("plot2")
      }
      if(input$my_choices == "Plot2"){
        hide("plot1");show("plot2")
      }
    }

    else{

      if(all(c("Plot1","Plot2") %in% input$my_choices)){
        show("plot1");show("plot2")
      }
    }
  },ignoreNULL = F)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: love your new solution!! it works perfectly, and i get to know of the package shinyjs. Thanks so much! (: